# How ro reduce bar height - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, charts

I'm using bar-chart from chart.js with bootstrap. `canvas` is wrapped within a div having class `col-md-8`. It works fine but the height of bar is too high.

I found `barWIdth` property that could be changed but was unable to find any `barHeight` property. So how to charge the bar-height?

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Too Much Bar Height]

Edit: After change its height via css, labels are compress

[image: Compressed labels]

Comment: Reduce the size of the graph?

Comment: resizing it via css compresses label. see added attachment.

Comment: Did you do this via Firebug etc?

Comment: @Kanav did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Give your chart a height?

```
<div class="graph-container">
     <!-- Your graph element -->
     <canvas id="graph"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then in your css file

```
.graph-container  canvas {

     height: 300px; /* Example... */
 }
```

Or simply

```
#graph {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Using this technique compresses labels. See added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, set `maintainAspectRatio` to `false`

```
    type: 'bar',
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
```

Then, you can play with the chart's height using CSS if you want to maintain a certain height *(that will not affect the labels)*, or leave it as it is.