# Reduce spacing between bars in horizontal bar chart (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following horizontal bar chart

```
<template>
<div>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            ctx: null,
            chart: null,
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                datasets: [{
                    categoryPercentage: 0.4,
                    label: 'Stars',
                    data: [15, 28, 34, 48, 100],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',

                    ],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        categoryPercentage: 0.4
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to reduce the spacing between one bar and the other (not eliminate it, just reduce it), but I don't know how to do this, if I use the `categoryPercentage` prop it does about the same as `barPercentage`, just reduces the size of the bar itself but not the distance between each bar.

This is how is looking right now
[image]

If possible I would also have the chart in a blank canvas too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203301/how-ro-reduce-bar-height-chart-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bar width is influenced through the options [`barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration), which both need to be defined on the dataset.

To find out about the relationship between `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage`, see [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage).

Please take a look at your amended runnable code below:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    datasets: [{
      barPercentage: 0.9,
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      label: 'Stars',
      data: [15, 28, 34, 48, 100],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)',
        'rgba(178, 140, 129, 0.2)'
      ],
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

> In case you simply want to see the existing bars closer to each other, you need to change the height of the chart. This can be done directly on the `canvas` through the `height` attribute. Alternatively you may also enclose the `canvas` in a `div` that has its dimensions defined by some `CSS`.