# can we reduce the gap between chart bars?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

i have used chart.js horizontal bar. and below is my code. i want to reduce the gap highlighted in 2 bars in image.

let chartOptions = {
responsive: true,
responsiveAnimationDuration: 1,
maintainApectRatio: true,
aspectRatio: 1,
legend: false,
tooltips: { enabled: false },
gridlines: false,
scales: {
xAxes: [
{
ticks: { display: false },
stacked: false,
gridLines: {
display: false,
drawBorder: false
}
}
],
yAxes: [
{
ticks: { display: false },
stacked: true,
barPercentage: 0.7,
categoryPercentage: 0.5,
gridLines: {
display: false,
drawBorder: false
}
}
]
},
animation: {
onComplete: this.generateImage,
onProgress() {
const chartInstance = this.chart;
const ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
const dataset = this.data.datasets[0];
const meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(0);

```
        Chart.helpers.each(
          meta.data.forEach((bar, index) => {
            const value = this.data.datasets[0].data[index] + "%";
            const label = this.data.labels[index];
            const labelPositionX = 14;
            const labelWidth =
              ctx.measureText(label).width + labelPositionX;

            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.textAlign = "left";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
            ctx.fillText(label, labelPositionX, bar._model.y);
            ctx.fillText(value, 170, bar._model.y);
          })
        );
      }
    }
  };

  let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_fdsSubmission");

  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    data: {
      labels: ["Submitted Courses", "Not Submitted Courses"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "%",
          data: [
            // this.fdSubmittedCoursesPercentageVal,
            // this.fdNotSubmittedCoursesPercentageVal
            // // , this.fdiaPercentageVal
            10, 5
          ],
          backgroundColor: "#6db4e0"
        },
        {
          label: "Complete",
          data: [
            100 - this.fdSubmittedCoursesPercentageVal,
            100 - this.fdNotSubmittedCoursesPercentageVal
            // 100 - this.fdiaPercentageVal
          ],
          backgroundColor: "#e7e7e7",
          borderColor: "#e7e7e7",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#e7e7e7",
          hoverBorderColor: "#e7e7e7"
        }
      ]
    },
    options: chartOptions
  });
  this.chart = myChart;
},
```

also how to place labels i.e submitted and not submitted courses above the bars

Comment: You should tag the chart library you are using.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: You should add the tag for it.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914817/2358409